# How can we see the diff view for edits to a post?

Tags: support, revisions-list, diff

When someone edits my post, the edit summary helps but if I could see a diff view (similar to git) that'd be good. It would allow me to see exactly what was changed between revisions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see what was changed if you click on the edit's timestamp:

> [image]

That will take you to the revisions page that contains all the changes made to the post:

> [image: revisions]

You can also choose to view "side-by-side markdown" diff, that will show changes not visible in the ordinary diff, e.g. adding blank spaces, changing URL of links etc:

> [image]

Comment: I didn't know that!  Good answer!

Comment: @alexy, if not in the above revision history, then where did you see the edit summary?

Comment: this is also in the [faq#editing] now with a picture as well